# How to convert Number in word in Twig File

Tags: twig

I want to convert Price:200$ in words like Price:Two Hundred$.

In twig like this {{ price }} but this is show Number.

Can any one know how it is possible show this price in word in Twig ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twig won't show anything spelled out without adding this functionality. Check out craue's TwigExtensionsBundle, it contains a Twig Extension with a filter for spelling out numbers.

https://github.com/craue/TwigExtensionsBundle

Usage:

```
spelled out number: {{ price | craue_spellout }}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Intl filter provided by the official Twig's extensions repository can spellout numbers:

```
{{ 19.2|localizednumber('spellout') }}
{# Output: nineteen point two #}
```

For this filter to work,  the PHP intl extension is needed and the `twig/extensions` package must be installed.

If you use Twig directly, register the extension like this:

```
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl());
```

If you use Symfony, register this service:

```
services:
    Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl:
        class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl
        private: true
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [twigphp/twig-extensions official docs](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig-extensions), **twigphp/twig-extensions** is now deprecated. However, there's an excellent alternative available.

For **Twig 3.X**, the **format_number** filter is available as described in the [official Twig doc](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/format_number.html).

However, this filter **is not available by default**, so we need to install it in our project:

```bash
composer require twig/intl-extra
```

Additionally, we'll need to install:

```bash
composer require twig/extra-bundle
```

After that, in our twig file, we can simply use the shortcut filter **format_spellout_number**

```
{{ sale.total | format_spellout_number }}
```

And voilá!